# Send mail from gmail using SMTPMailer in flex AIR app

Tags: apache-flex, email, air, smtp, gmail

I am trying to connect to my gmail account via smtp using port 465 in order to sent emails from inside my app but connection fails...my code is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[       
        import org.smtp.*;
        import org.smtp.events.SMTPEvent;
        import org.smtp.mailer.SMTPMailer;
        private function sendIt():void{ 

            var host:String = "smtp.gmail.com";
            var port:int = 465;     
            var login:String = "mygmail@gmail.com";
            var pass:String = "mypassword";

            var mailer:SMTPMailer = new SMTPMailer(host,port);

            mailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.MAIL_ERROR,function(e:SMTPEvent):void{
            trace("error:"+e.toString());});

            mailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.AUTHENTICATED,function(e:SMTPEvent):void{
            trace("authent:"+e.toString());});

            mailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.BAD_SEQUENCE,function(e:SMTPEvent):void{
            trace("bad:"+e.toString());});

            mailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.CONNECTED,function(e:SMTPEvent):void{
            trace("connected:"+e.toString());});

            mailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.DISCONNECTED,function(e:SMTPEvent):void{
                trace("disconnected:"+e.toString());});

            mailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.MAIL_SENT,function(e:SMTPEvent):void{
            trace("mailsent:"+e.toString());});

            mailer.connect(host, port);
            mailer.authenticate(login,pass);


            var subject:String = "Got new MAil";
            var message:String = "new email using SMTPMailer";
            var from:String = "mygmail@gmail.com";
            var to:String = "mygmail@gmail.com";
            mailer.sendHTMLMail(from,to,subject,message);
            trace(mailer.connected);
            trace("end");

        }

]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Button x="281" y="146" label="Send it!"
          click="sendIt();"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

but it does not connect to send the mail!! what am i doing wrong??

Thanks a lot beforehand!

PS: [SMTPMailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27)

Comment: myabe because you're sending mail to your self, are you using the correct authenticate info

Comment: Most likely a crossdomain.xml file doesn't exist; therefore Flash can't directly call that server.  But, I didn't see your 'host' defined anywhere in the code so can't actually check.

Comment: @mgraph Yes i am using the same to login from the gmail.com page!

Comment: @www.Flextras.com i have declared var host:String = "smtp.gmail.com";
at the top!..any help or any example that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using Airxmail: http://code.google.com/p/airxmail/

Comment: Could you share some code - i have TLSEngine shutdown triggered by Error: Cannot verify certificate always